# Accessing ItemsSource from GridView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button, When it's clicked it populates my Datagrid. The code is written within the .xaml.cs file, which I believe breaks the MVVM rule but it's just a temporary situation. I know it's not ideal for MVVM.

Calculate.xaml.cs

```
public void PopulateGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BindableCollection<Payments> PaymentCollection = new BindableCollection<Payments>
    ....
    Datagrid.ItemsSource = PaymentCollection
    ....
}
```

My question is if there's a way to read the Datagrids ItemsSource From the ViewModel.

What I've Tried

LoansViewModel

```
public BindableCollection<Payments> paymentCollection {get; set;}
```

Calculate.xaml

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding paymentCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```

The collection paymentCollection Doesn't Update after calculate is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this the correct MVVM way. Get rid of your PopulateGrid method in the .xaml.cs file and eliminate setting the Click property in your xaml. Instead bind the command property of the button to an ICommand property in your ViewModel the same way you are binding the ItemsSource of the RadGridView. You will need an implementation of ICommand to use and MVVM Lights RelayCommand is one option for that.

Here is the code for the ICommand:

```
private ICommand _populateGridCommand;
public ICommand PopulateGridCommand
{
   get
   {
      if (_populateGridCommand == null)
      {
         _populateGridCommand = new RelayCommand(() => PopulateGrid());
      }
      return _populateGridCommand;
   }
}

public void PopulateGrid()
{
   PaymentCollection.Clear();
   //load data and then add to the collection
}
```

**UPDATE**

To do this in code behind, you'll need to access the ViewModel and work on the collection from it. I don't like this but it should work.

```
public void PopulateGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var loansVM = DataGrid.DataContext as LoansViewModel;
   loansVM.paymentsCollection.Clear();
   var newData = //load data
   foreach (var data in newData)
      loansVM.paymentsCollection.Add(data);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I definitely like your approach. Within the LoansViewModel I initiated paymentsCollection = new BindableCollection<PaymentInfo>() but I still get a null reference  using the updated code, break is at loansVM.paymentsCollection.Clear();

Comment: Which value is null, the loansVM or the paymentsCollection?

Comment: LoansVm is null, AmortGrid.DataContext has value

Comment: is the RadGridView named "DataGrid" in your xaml? Whatever the name of that control is what you need to use instead of DataGrid. If that doesn't work, then your issue isn't reproducible based on the code you have posted.

Comment: It's Matching. But thank you for your help, definitely appreciated. Guess I gotta try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your xaml code looks like it should work provided the DataContext of your grid is set to your ViewModel instance where your paymentCollection property is declared.

Once your binding is set, it calls the get on the paymentCollection property. If your collection property object is not reassigned any further, and you add and remove elements from it, and it notifies on those changes via INotifyCollectionChanged, it will work.  This is how ObservableCollection works and used most commonly for such scenarios.

However, if when you calculate, you re-assign your paymentCollection property with a new instance, your grid will not update, because you now have an entirely different collection.  In that case you will need to notify the view that the paymentCollection property itself has changed.  In which case you should implement it as a notification property:

```
    private BindableCollection<Payments>_paymentCollection;
    public BindableCollection<Payments> paymentCollection {
        get { return _paymentCollection; }
        set {
            _paymentCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("paymentCollection");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also it is good practice to capitalize property names as in C#, i.e. PaymentCollection

Comment: Hi Bedo, I definitely Like your Approach. Within <Telerik:RadGridView DataContext="LoansViewModel"...> But it still remains the same. The Collection remains zeros and doesn't update. May I ask if I'm setting my datacontext correctly?

Comment: I also tried this: 
var paymentCollection= DataGrid.DataContext as LoanViewModel;
if (paymentCollection== null)
                return;
            paymentCollection.paymentCollection= PopulateGrid();

Comment: The problem is that you aren't doing this in the ViewModel but rather the code behind. So, even though you start out with it bound to the collection in your ViewModel, when you click the button you replace the ItemsSource with a new collection from your code behind. This is why the approach in my answer is the way to fix it.

Comment: I'm trying not to convert my code to MVVM though. @LeeO. The calculate code is written behind and is huge. It's not simple for me to just bring the PopulateGrid() over to the ViewModel

Comment: Then why do you have a ViewModel?

Comment: The ViewModel does have functions within it. If it was simple as cut and paste it would already be in the viewmodel and I wouldn't be posting this question.

Comment: Are you sure your view's DataContext object is assigned to your viewmodel object?  Do you have some code that explicitly does something like myWindow.DataContext = new LoanViewModel();?  Or are you using some framework.  Try debugging your binding first to see if everything checks out: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html